# The function cell.Text() does not work when calling sheets

Tags: excel, vba, reference, cell

I have a workbook that has 10 tabs, some are hidden, but I don't think it matters for my purpose. On the "SQL" tab, I have a mapping of what I want the new sheet name to be (see A14:B24). I gave cell A15 a named range SheetStart for offsetting purposes in the code. You can ignore everything else on the sheet. When I run my macro, the debug.print sheetName is $200,000 which is correct, but on the next line when I assign "Option 1", it says subscript out of range. I think the issue is with using .Text(). Can someone explain why that is? What is the work around this?

[image]

```
Sub UpdateSheetNames()
        Dim SheetStart As Range
        Dim wb2 As Workbook
        Dim sheetName As String
        Dim formattedCell As Range

        Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
        Set SheetStart = wb2.Sheets("SQL").Range("SheetStart")
        
        wb2.Activate
        For i = 1 To 10
            ' Get the formatted value from the cell
            Set formattedCell = SheetStart.Offset(i - 1, 0)
            sheetName = formattedCell.Text
            ' Remove any invalid characters for sheet names
            sheetName = Replace(Replace(sheetName, "/", "_"), "\", "_")
            ' Check if the sheet name is too long (Excel limits sheet names to 31 characters)
            If Len(sheetName) > 31 Then
                sheetName = Trim(Left(sheetName, 31))
            End If
            Debug.Print sheetName
            Sheets(sheetName).Name = "Option " & i 'subscript error here
            Sheets("Summary").Range("Sheet" & i).Value = "Option " & i
            
        Next i
End Sub
```

I tried manually setting sheetName = "$200,000" and it works fine. That's how I knew the issue was with the .Text function.

Comment: If your Debug.Print gives you "$200,00" then that's not the same as your sheetname "$200,000", you're effectively missing a 0 unless this was a typo in your question?

Comment: Sorry, typo in question. Edited.

Comment: Probably an unforeseen formatting issue, try using `Debug.Print "T" & sheetName & "T"` and then go character by character in the Debug screen from T to T. In my European monetary notation, there's an extra space (don't ask me why) between the € and the number. I can't see one on your image but maybe there's still something invisible there. Or there's one on your sheetname prior to this. Oh, suppose JohnM beat me to it ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be with 'rogue' space characters before and/or after the value returned by `.Text` ... replace the relevant line with this to remove them

```
sheetName = Trim(Replace(Replace(sheetName, "/", "_"), "\", "_"))
```